# Join one to many get one row, by priority

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a contacts table:

```
ID  NAME
--- ----
1   KK
2   JKI
3   HU
```

And I have a phone table:

```
ID  ContactID  Phone  Type
--- ---------  -----  --------
1   1          569    Business
2   1          896    Mobile
3   1          258    Fax
4   2          369    Mobile
5   3          124    Fax
6   2          496    Fax
```

I want to get all contacts with at least one phone number. The phone number to be displayed should be Business, if there are no Busniess Type available, then Mobile, if there are no Mobile type available then Fax else null

Sample Result:

```
ID  NAME   PHONE
--- ------ ------
1   KK     569   -- Business present
2   JKI    369   -- Business not present but mobile present
3   HU     124   -- only fax present
```

Comment: Please don't use a hundred `&nbsp;` characters to try and format. Just highlight your code and hit the `{}` button. Also can you explain how you can get null if you want "all contacts with at least one phone number"? Are there phone types you haven't told us about?

Comment: Pardon my word usage. When I said at least one phone number, I meant of the 3 types (Business, Mobile and Fax, if they are present) and I expected a null phone number if there are no phone rows available for that contact. Thank you for your suggestion with the code format. I am new and learning

Comment: So does that mean the only possible phone types are `Business`, `Mobile` and `Fax`? Or if someone has a phone type of `Emergency` what do you want returned?

Comment: Those are the only 3 phone types (Business, Mobile and Fax) at the present

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH [prior](i,t) AS 
(
    SELECT 1, 'Business'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Mobile'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Fax'
),
x AS 
(
  SELECT c.ID, c.Name, p.Phone,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY r.i)
  FROM dbo.Contacts AS c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Phone AS p
  ON p.ContactID = c.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [prior] AS r
  ON r.t = p.[Type]
)
SELECT ID, Name, Phone FROM x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you want to eliminate contacts with no phones, just change both instances of `LEFT OUTER` to `INNER`.

Comment: +1 - always nice to see a solution with window functions. I thought about it but I was to lazy to do it due to the priority issue. Note that your code may not return the expected results if phone numbers with a type that isn't in the priority list are present in the table; you'd have to use another CTE or nested query to do a normal join between Phone and Prior before the outer join with that. Also you should quote the identifier "type": `[Type]`

Comment: @Lucero I assumed we were told about all the possible types.

Answer (score 3):

```
select  c.ID
,       c.Name
,       coalesce(business.Phone, mobile.Phone, fax.Phone) as Phone
from    Contacts c
left join
        Phone business
on      business.ContactID = c.ID
        and business.type = 'Business'
left join
        Phone mobile
on      mobile.ContactID = c.ID
        and mobile.type = 'Mobile'
left join
        Phone fax
on      fax.ContactID = c.ID
        and fax.type = 'Fax'
where   coalesce(business.Phone, mobile.Phone, fax.Phone) is not null
```

Comment: Yep, a good solution. However, I think you can omit the WHERE clause since the OP asked to get null if no phone number is found.

Comment: @Lucero: yeah, the question does looks ambiguous

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I actually want to see all contacts. If there is any one of the three phone numbers (Business, Mobile and Fax) available then it would show as per the priority else it would show null value under the phone column. There are only 3 phone types.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is not great for querying this efficiently, but this may do the trick:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.Name, COALESCE(
    (SELECT TOP 1 P.Phone FROM Phones P WHERE P.ContactID = C.ID AND P.[Type] = 'Business'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 P.Phone FROM Phones P WHERE P.ContactID = C.ID AND P.[Type] = 'Mobile'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 P.Phone FROM Phones P WHERE P.ContactID = C.ID AND P.[Type] = 'Fax')
  ) Phone
  FROM Contacts C
```

Comment: "I want to get all contacts with atleast one phone number"

Comment: @Andomar, "[...]  if there are no Mobile type available then Fax **else null**" - as you said, it seems a bit ambiguous ;)

Comment: If none of the three phone types are available, the record would show the ID, Name and NULL under the Phone Column. There are only 3 types available no more. I hope this clears the ambiguity. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The most compact solution I can think of is,

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
    c.ID, c.NAME, p.Phone
    , r = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY CASE p.[TYPE] WHEN 'Business' THEN 1 WHEN 'Mobile' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)
    FROM Contacts c
    LEFT JOIN Phone p ON p.ContactID = c.ID AND p.[TYPE] IN ('Business','Mobile','Fax')
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Phone WHERE ContactID = c.ID)
)
SELECT ID, NAME, Phone
FROM CTE
WHERE r = 1;
```

This solution returns,

- Contacts with the first matching phone in the specified order
- Contact with NULL phone # if a phone # exists but none of the specified types
- No result for Contacts having no phone at all